# Problems building ICU

Tags: c++, build, makefile, solaris, icu

I'm trying to build ICU on Solaris Sparc 64 and it's giving me this error when calling make:

> *** No rule to make target `uconvmsg/libuconvmsg.a(uconvmsg/uconvmsg_dat.ao', needed by`uconvmsg/libuconvmsg.a'.  Stop

There seems to be a bug with make 3.8.2 that causes this:
http://lists.linuxtogo.org/pipermail/openembedded-core/2012-November/031740.html

But I tried GNU make 3.74 and still getting the same error. Did anyone have the same problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

workaround- if you don't need uconv you can configure ICU with `--disable-extras` (and file a bug)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I got the answer from ICU developers a while ago but was too busy to come back and add an answer. Thanks though. This will be helpful for future developers!

Comment: Wow that is awesome. Thank you! I just want to let you know that getting an answer from a developer of ICU is something pretty amazing for a college student like me! :)

Comment: @DaoLam well that is part of the benefit of open source software, there is the emphasis on building community.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, using gmake 3.81 worked for me.

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I tried 3.8, 3.81, 3.82 and none of them worked! :(